# Basic Python Algorithm : reading two data sets and do operations with them

Tags: python, algorithm

maybe a basic question. I've got a data file with two column, like this.

```
80696,23.00
```

80397,23.00

80397,23.00

80699,22.00

now, i would like to add 100 to a number in the first column each time the second one changes by one point. If it doesn't change do nothing. so i will have an output like :

```
80696,23.00
```

80397,23.00

80397,23.00

**80799**,22.00

any help will be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: And what have you tried doing so far?

Comment: Try looping over the dataframe with .iterrows()

Comment: @ UnholySheep i've just used some basic zip/numpy operations  ' 
'

Comment: @Roelant , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(from comment to answer)

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if idx > 1 and row[1] != oldrow[1]:
         df.ix[idx,0] += 100
    oldrow = row
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time/help!

Comment: No worries - Could you accept my answer if it solved the problem? :)

Comment: gives me File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 793, in pandas.tslib.get_value_box (pandas/tslib.c:16774)
IndexError: index out of bounds

Comment: Made a change in the code, works for me on your example DFs